# Shen tutorial example for typed function does not compile

Tags: shen

I just discovered the Shen language and so I installed it under my debian linux as an SBCL build and started to work through the [Shen in 15 minutes](https://shenlanguage.org/OSM/15min.html) tutorial.

I made it up to the point, where you turn on type checking, using

> Shen, copyright (C) 2010-2015 Mark Tarver
> [www.shenlanguage.org](http://www.shenlanguage.org), Shen 22.2
> running under Common Lisp, implementation: SBCL
> port 3.0.3 ported by Mark Tarver, Robert Koeninger and Bruno Deferrari

```
(tc +)
(define total
  (list number) --> number
  [] -> 0
  [X | Y] -> (+ X (total Y)))
```

Entering the above sequence in the repl or storing it into a `.shen` file and then `(load "in15min.shen")` yields the unexpected:

> [list number] is not a legitimate constructor

and trying to evaluate it anyway, I get a `type error` as output.

So here my questions:

- Is the tutorial outdated and the syntax has changed?
- Or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering from the style sheet has missed {}s.

```
    (define total
    {(list number) --> number}
    [] -> 0
    [X | Y] -> (+ X (total Y)))
```

is right.

Mark